# How can I do destructuring assignment in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, destructuring

I have the following function.

```
 returnStateElement = (...elements) => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    return elements.reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: copy[key] }), {});
  };
```

Working:

```
f = () => {
const dataSender = this.returnStateElement('email', 'password');
let { email, password } = dataSender;
console.log(dataSender,email,password);
}
```

Not working:

```
f2 = () => {
const { email, password } = dataSender = this.returnStateElement('email', 'password');
console.log(dataSender,email,password);
}
```

Is there a way to make a more compact type of assignment like f2()?

Comment: Can't reproduce this - I tried this in the console: `const { x, y } = z = { x: 5, y: 6 };`, which works fine

Comment: It can be a dumb question but why would you need a middle variable on this assignment?

Comment: I know, but what I need is to check certain fields not all what I take from the returnStateElement function and then pass all the values ​​that are inside the main function ie dataSender send them via fetch.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @adiga: in the function f2(), there is no visibility of the variable, it is not seen.

Comment: You cannot do this in one line. You should use `f` because it's easily readable. There is no difference in performance in using 2 separate lines so there's nothing to be gained from this. In `f2`, `dataSender` is created as a global varaible because you don't use `const`. Only one liner solution is to use a comma in between `const dataSender = this.returnStateElement('email', 'password'), { email, password } = dataSender` but that's not a big improvement over what you already have

Answer (score -1):

The following should work, you don't have to assign the results to an intermediate variable, you just need to provide the exact names that are in the returned object

```
f2 = () => {
const { email, password } = this.returnStateElement('email', 'password');
console.log(dataSender,email,password);
}
```

Example

```
const foo = () => {
    return {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2'
  }
}

const bar = () => {
    const { a, b } = foo();
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
}

bar();
// Logs 1, 2
```

Comment: I know, but what I need is to check certain fields not all what I take from the returnStateElement function and then pass all the values ​​that are inside the main function ie dataSender send them via fetch.

Answer (score -1):

```js
f2 = () => {
  const { email, password, ...rest } = this.returnStateElement('email', 'password');
  console.log(email,password, rest);
  // you can combine all like
  console.log({...rest, email, password });
}
```

Comment: I know, but what I need is to check certain fields not all what I take from the returnStateElement function and then pass all the values ​​that are inside the main function ie dataSender send them via fetch.